# Win32 API COM port communication reads 0x20 instead of 0x00

Tags: winapi, serial-port

I am reading from COM port (communicating with RS-232).

I noticed a strange behavior when Win32 was reading 0x00 characters. I confirmed it by sending all possible combinations (from 0x00 to 0xF):

[image: 0x20 0x00]

0x00 is read as 0x20.

Since my code can read all other Hex data, it is not a code issue right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ANSWER TO MY QUESTION:

I forgot I replaced the input 0 character with the space character:

```
else if(buf[i] == 0)
{
    //usually this happens in the beggining of a line.
    buf[i] = ' ';//null
}
```

because usually every line I was reading was starting with 0.

So I removed the above code in my main and it fixed